# how to send data to to mssql server from python raspberry pi?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, wxpython, pyodbc

I have make a button/ switch circuit with program that will display it outpu using wxPython but i want to send the data to the server.

This is by button program:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import datetime
import os

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(40, GPIO.IN)

global count, flag
count = 0
flag = 0
button = "None"
input = GPIO.input(40)

global update_time
update_time = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), '%d-%m-%y     %H:%M:%S')

try:
    import wx
except ImportError:
    raise ImportError, "The wxPython module is required to run this program."

class OnOffApp_wx(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, size = (500, 200), title = 'ON / OFF Status')
        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.WHITE)
        self.SetWindowStyle(wx.STAY_ON_TOP)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer()
        font = wx.Font(20, wx.DECORATIVE, wx.ITALIC, wx.NORMAL)
        self.SetFont(font)

        self.label1 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, label=u'Button Status : {}'.format(button))
        self.label1.SetBackgroundColour(wx.WHITE)
        self.label1.SetForegroundColour(wx.BLACK)
        sizer.Add(self.label1, (1,0), (1,2), wx.EXPAND)

        self.label2 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, label=u'Flag Status : {}'.format(flag))
        self.label2.SetBackgroundColour(wx.WHITE)
        self.label2.SetForegroundColour(wx.BLACK)
        sizer.Add(self.label2, (2,0), (1,3), wx.EXPAND)

        self.label3 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, label=u'Count Status : {}'.format(count))
        self.label3.SetBackgroundColour(wx.WHITE)
        self.label3.SetForegroundColour(wx.BLACK)
        sizer.Add(self.label3, (3,0), (1,4), wx.EXPAND)

        self.label4 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, label=u'Time Updated : {}'.format(update_time))
        self.label4.SetBackgroundColour(wx.WHITE)
        self.label4.SetForegroundColour(wx.BLACK)
        sizer.Add(self.label4, (4,0), (1,5), wx.EXPAND)

        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.on_timer, self.timer)
        self.timer.Start(50)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Show(True)

    def on_timer(self,event):
        global update_time
        update_time = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), '%d-%m-%y    %H:%M:%S')

        global count, flag                                 
        input = GPIO.input(40)
        if ((not flag) and input):
            flag = input
            count += 1
            button = 'Pressed'
            #self.label1.SetLabel("Button Status : Pressed")
            self.label1.SetLabel("Button Status : {}".format(button))
            self.label2.SetLabel("Flag Status : {}".format(flag))
            self.label3.SetLabel("Count Status : {}".format(count))
            self.label4.SetLabel("Time Updated : {}".format(update_time))

        elif ((not input) and flag):
            flag = input
            count += 1
            button = 'Debounce'
            #self.label1.SetLabel("Button Status : Debounce")
            self.label1.SetLabel("Button Status : {}".format(button))
            self.label2.SetLabel("Flag Status : {}".format(flag))
            self.label3.SetLabel("Count Status : {}".format(count))
            self.label4.SetLabel("Time Updated : {}".format(update_time))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Rs = wx.App()
    OnOffApp_wx(None, -1, 'ON / OFF Status')
    Rs.MainLoop()

GPIO.cleanup()
```

This my sql example connection in python as I follow from this 2 website which is https://tryolabs.com/blog/2012/06/25/connecting-sql-server-database-python-under-ubuntu/ and https://gist.github.com/rduplain/1293636 :

```
import pyodbc

dsn = 'datasource'
user = 'username'
password = 'password'
database = 'databasename'

con_string = 'DSN=%s; UID=%s; PWD=%s; DATABASE=%s;' % (dsn, user, password, database)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(con_string)
```

i cannot give you my database information but can anyone show how to send data to the mssql database from my button switch program as I have succesfully connected to my server and database.

Comment: so whats the problem? You have already connected, is there something wrong with the sending of data or is it that you don't know how to send the data? If the latter, see [here](https://mkleehammer.github.io/pyodbc/)

Comment: i don't know on how to send it as i has't done it yet.

Comment: i only whant to send the flag and count data into the table in the database for starter.

Answer (score 0):

Here my successfull code that can send data to the server except for the datetime that it sen my update_time like 1-12-2016 but when i use select to view data in mssql server it display Jan 12 2016.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import datetime
import os
import pyodbc

dsn = 'sqlserverdatasource'
driver = 'FreeTDS'
user = 'username'
password = 'password'
database = 'databasename'

con_string = 'DSN=%s; DRIVER=%s; UID=%s; PWD=%s; DATABASE=%s;' % (dsn, driver, user, password, database)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(con_string)
global cursor
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(40, GPIO.IN)

global count, flag
count = 0
flag = 0
button = "None"
input = GPIO.input(40)

global update_time
update_time = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), '%d-%m-%y     %H:%M:%S')

try:
    import wx
except ImportError:
    raise ImportError, "The wxPython module is required to run this program."

class OnOffApp_wx(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, size = (500, 200), title = 'ON / OFF Status')
        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.WHITE)
        self.SetWindowStyle(wx.STAY_ON_TOP)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer()
        font = wx.Font(20, wx.DECORATIVE, wx.ITALIC, wx.NORMAL)
        self.SetFont(font)

        self.label1 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, label=u'Button Status : {}'.format(button))
        self.label1.SetBackgroundColour(wx.WHITE)
        self.label1.SetForegroundColour(wx.BLACK)
        sizer.Add(self.label1, (1,0), (1,2), wx.EXPAND)

        self.label2 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, label=u'Flag Status : {}'.format(flag))
        self.label2.SetBackgroundColour(wx.WHITE)
        self.label2.SetForegroundColour(wx.BLACK)
        sizer.Add(self.label2, (2,0), (1,3), wx.EXPAND)

        self.label3 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, label=u'Count Status : {}'.format(count))
        self.label3.SetBackgroundColour(wx.WHITE)
        self.label3.SetForegroundColour(wx.BLACK)
        sizer.Add(self.label3, (3,0), (1,4), wx.EXPAND)

        self.label4 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, label=u'Time Updated : {}'.format(update_time))
        self.label4.SetBackgroundColour(wx.WHITE)
        self.label4.SetForegroundColour(wx.BLACK)
        sizer.Add(self.label4, (4,0), (1,5), wx.EXPAND)

        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.on_timer, self.timer)
        self.timer.Start(50)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Show(True)

    def on_timer(self,event):
        global update_time
        update_time = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), '%d-%m-%y    %H:%M:%S')

        global count, flag                                 
        input = GPIO.input(40)
        cursor = cnxn.cursor()

        if ((not flag) and input):
            flag = input
            count += 1
            button = 'Pressed'
            #self.label1.SetLabel("Button Status : Pressed")
            self.label1.SetLabel("Button Status : {}".format(button))
            self.label2.SetLabel("Flag Status : {}".format(flag))
            self.label3.SetLabel("Count Status : {}".format(count))
            self.label4.SetLabel("Time Updated : {}".format(update_time))
            #cursor.execute("INSERT INTO  TableTest (Col1, Col2, Col3) VALUES(%s,%s)"%(int(flag),int(count)))
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO  TableTest (Col1, Col2, Col3) VALUES(%s,%s,'%s')"%(int(flag),int(count),update_time))
            cnxn.commit()

        elif ((not input) and flag):
            flag = input
            count += 1
            button = 'Debounce'
            #self.label1.SetLabel("Button Status : Debounce")
            self.label1.SetLabel("Button Status : {}".format(button))
            self.label2.SetLabel("Flag Status : {}".format(flag))
            self.label3.SetLabel("Count Status : {}".format(count))
            self.label4.SetLabel("Time Updated : {}".format(update_time))
            #cursor.execute("INSERT INTO  TableTest (Col1, Col2, Col3) VALUES(%s,%s)"%(int(flag),int(count)))
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO  TableTest (Col1, Col2, Col3) VALUES(%s,%s,'%s')"%(int(flag),int(count),update_time))
            cnxn.commit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Rs = wx.App()
    OnOffApp_wx(None, -1, 'ON / OFF Status')
    Rs.MainLoop()

GPIO.cleanup()
cursor.close()
cnxn.close()
```

Comment: Now can anyone help to create and display data from server using select statement by adding button and the output appear in a message box